# Add data to child table using parent data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a parent table: OBSTACLES and a child table AREA 2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OBSTACLES] (
    [ob_fid]  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [RECORD_IDENTIFIER]  INT,
    [aero_surv_fid] INT
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AREA 2] (
    [a2_fid]  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
        [ob_fid]  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[OBSTACLES]([ob_fid]) ON UPDATE AND DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I have a twin value data source which matches one of the [RECORD_IDENTIFIER] & [aero_surv_fid] values in [dbo].[OBSTACLES].

I wish to populate [dbo].[AREA 2] with the corresponding [ob_fid] from its parent.

So to clarify, I start with two non-unique values, then I find the corresponding unique value, and insert that into the child table.

I have been using this SQL to insert a single row of data in the child table:

```
DECLARE @ob_fid INT 
SET @ob_fid = (SELECT [ob_fid] FROM [dbo].[OBSTACLES] where [RECORD_IDENTIFIER] = 1021 AND [aero_surv_fid] = 2) 
IF @ob_fid IS NOT NULL INSERT INTO [dbo].[AREA 2] ([ob_fid]) VALUES (@ob_fid)
```

While this does produce a result it takes a very long time. Especially when doing it 1000s of times. Is there a better query using the parent/child relationship instead of logic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```sql
DECLARE @AreasToInsert TABLE (RECORD_IDENTIFIER int, aero_surv_fid int)
INSERT INTO @AreasToInsert (RECORD_IDENTIFIER, aero_surv_fid)
VALUES (1021, 2), (etc, etc) -- Create this in Excel

INSERT INTO [AREA 2] (ob_fid) 
SELECT ob_fid 
FROM OBSTACLES obs
INNER JOIN @AreasToInsert a ON obs.RECORD_IDENTIFIER = a.RECORD_IDENTIFIER 
    AND obs.aero_surv_fid = a.aero_surv_fid
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the sort of thing I was looking for. However, when it came to running a 4000 item query it didn't take much time off the original 5-minute query. Failing for an even more optimized query I might have to boost my DTUs perhaps?

Comment: When you're inserting your 4000 items are you running the above 4000 times or selecting all 4000 as part of the above SELECT and inserting them all together? The latter would be quicker. How are you getting the values for the WHERE clause?

Comment: I am repeating the above 4000 times. I start with a list of number from 1000 to 5000 approximately and a fixed [aero_surv_fid] value of say 2 for all 4000 queries

Comment: I should mention I have a 4000 row excel spreadsheet which generates the above query 4000 times. I then paste it into SSMS. Is there a single better query I could use?

Comment: I edited my answer after reading your last comment but only just noticed the comment before that. I'm less clear what you're trying to do now. Are you trying to insert an ob_fid into [Area 2] for every existing [OBSTACLES] row with a given aero_surv_fid and a RECORD_IDENTIFIER between two values? If so see my second answer.

Comment: No sorry, I have a list of numbers approximately between 1000 and 5000. Not necessarily all of them though. The list is variable. 1000,1001,1005,1006 etc... aero_surv_fid is fixed per-query.

Comment: Your first answer was perfect but slow!

Comment: Have you tried the answer as it is now? i.e. insert the values from Excel into a memory table, then join the memory table to [OBSTACLES] to decide what to insert into [AREA 2]

Comment: Msg 10738, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.

Comment: How about if you only enter 1000 rows in line 3, then repeat lines 2 & 3 four times?